# Output dictionary of tuple keys and tuple values as latitude longitude data and plot it

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, dimensions

I have two samples of precipitation geographical data each sample is an array with dimensions as time, lat, lon coordinate. I applied a statistical test on these two samples and what I want to get as outcome is a series containing the test statistics ( there are two statistics) on a lat-lon grid. I then want to plot one of the test statistics values, on the lat-lon grid. What I did is defined as a dictionary called test, test={}, and then I applied the test as follows:

```
for ii in range(96):
     for jj in range(144):
         test[ii,jj]=stats.ks_2samp(year_avgprec1[:,ii,jj],year_avgprec2[:,ii,jj])
```

The outcome for test is a dictionary of the form

```
dict_keys([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), ... up to (96,144)
```

and

```
dict_values([Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.25, pvalue=0.571336004933722), Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.25, pvalue=0.571336004933722), Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.25, pvalue=0.571336004933722),...
```

How can I get my p-values and associate the dimensions lat - lon which are the keys of the dictionary (the 96x144, in order to plot it on a lat-lon grid) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for suggestions, the best I could come up with was:

```
matrix = []
for item in test:
   print(item,round(test[item][0],5))
   matrix.append(test[item][0])

x = np.reshape(matrix, (96, 144))
print(x.shape)
print(type(x))
```

This produces a 96x144 ( lat lon) matrix which I can then plot.
If any other more pythoninc suggestions I'm happy to read them.